# How to define shared generic Change Event type for diferent HTML elements in TypeScript and React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## I want to have one change event that can be used by Select or Input

I have an input component called `BuildingInfoInput` which renders a `TextField` or `Select` based on the availability of `options` prop.

```
import Label from "@/components/core/Label"
import TextField from "@/components/core/TextField"
import Tooltip from "@/components/core/Tooltip"
import styles from "./style.module.css"
import { Wrapper } from "../Wrapper"
import { IBuildingInfoInputProps } from "./type"
import Select from "@/components/core/Select"

export const BuildingInfoInput = ({
  id,
  value,
  label,
  tooltipText,
  unit,
  options,
  onValueChange,
}: IBuildingInfoInputProps) => {
  const { text, htmlFor } = label
  return (
    <Wrapper className={styles["field-wrapper"]}>
      <Wrapper className={styles["label-wrapper"]}>
        <Label text={text} htmlFor={htmlFor} />
        <Tooltip text={tooltipText} />
      </Wrapper>
      {options ? (
        <Select id={id} defaultValue={value as string} options={options} onSelect={onValueChange} />
      ) : (
        <TextField id={id} value={value as string} onChange={onValueChange} unit={unit} />
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

As you see in the code above, there's a change event called `onValueChange` , however this `event` is used for `input` and `select` in two props:

1. `onChange` for TextField component.
2. `onSelect` for Select component

I use my component `BuildingInfoInput` in a form  for different cases ( Textfield or Select ) like this:

1.Select

```
<BuildingInfoInput
          id='building-type'
          label={{ text: "Baujahr", htmlFor: "building-type" }}
          tooltipText=''
          value={buildingType}
          onValueChange={onConstructionYearChange} // issue is here
          options={buildingTypeOptions}
        />
```

2. TextField

```
 <BuildingInfoInput
          id='building-type'
          label={{ text: "Baujahr", htmlFor: "building-type" }}
          tooltipText=''
          value={buildingType}
          onValueChange={onBuildingTypeChange}
          options={buildingTypeOptions}
        />
```

Mu handlers for each Input:

```
const onBuildingTypeChange = ({ currentTarget }: SyntheticEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {

// Code here

}


  const onConstructionYearChange = ({ currentTarget }: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = Number(currentTarget.value)

    const isValidValue = isInteger(String(value)) && value <= 2023
    if (isValidValue) {
      setConstructionYear(value)
    }
    if (!currentTarget.value) {
      setConstructionYear("")
    }
  }
```

For the Textfield or `constructionYearEvent` I have this error:

[image]

For the Select or `buildingTypeEven` I have this error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>`?